# postgresql, how to insert elements on a table that references another table, but instead of referencing said table reference a derived table from it

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys

i have a table 'Compra' from which i derive 'CompraVirtual' and 'CompraFisica'. i also have table 'Comprobante' from which i derive 'Boleta' and 'Factura'. Comprobante has its foreign key referencing Compra in such a way that i can make, for example, Boleta be able to reference CompraVirtual, because each row of CompraVirtual or CompraFisica is also a row of Compra because of inheritance. however this:

```
INSERT INTO CompraFisica (ID, Fecha, Monto_total, Medio_Pago, DNI)  VALUES ('1',CURRENT_DATE,10.5,'si','20794189');
INSERT INTO Boleta (Numero, ID, DNI) VALUES ('1','1','15806955');
```

doesnt work. it only works when i make Boleta reference Compra and not CompraFisica, stating that there is no row in Compra with the desired id. how can i make this work?

i was expecting Comprobante to be able to reference any of the derived tables of Compra because of inheritance but it says it cant find the tables when trying to do that, and it only specifically works with Compra, not with any of its derived tables.

Comment: See [Don't do this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_table_inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a relationship with `Boleta` e `Compra`. By removing the table `CompraFisica` and adding a new row named `tipo` to indentify if the `compra` is "virtual" ou "física".

After it you need to create a new relationship `Boleta` e `Compra` and setting the foreign key to the table `compra`

Answer (score 0):

Consider redefining your database structure. Instead of directly referencing the derived tables `CompraFisica` and `CompraVirtual` from `Boleta`, introduce a new column, say `tipo`, in the `Compra` table to distinguish between "virtual" and "physical" purchases.

Then, create a relationship between `Boleta` and `Compra` using a foreign key linked to the `Compra` table, allowing you to reference both `CompraFisica` and `CompraVirtual` through this common link.